# New Line in Constant error when trying to insert escape character in string

Tags: c#, .net, string, insert

I am writing some C# code in which I am fetching values from the database and using it.  The problem I am facing is as below.

If my fetched value from the database is:

```
string cat1 = "sotheby's";
```

Now while using `cat1` I want to insert an escape character before the single quote.  To achieve this I have written the below code:

```
string cat1 = "sotheby's";

if (cat1.Contains("'")) {
    var indexofquote = cat1.IndexOf("'");
    cat1.Insert(indexofquote-1,"\");
    var cat2 = cat1;
}
```

The error arises on the insert line with the backslash (escape character). The error is New Line in Constant.

Please help me correct this error.

Comment: Well you need to escape it like `"\\"` or change it to `@"\"`

Comment: Side note: there is a good chance that right solution is using existing JSON serialization would more reliably escape characters to be used in JavaScript/ web services...

Comment: Wherever this string is heading, there's almost certainly an already built solution that is better than manually escaping `'` characters.

Comment: Also, [`String.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert.aspx): "Returns a **new** string in which ..."

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can't just write `"\"` in C# code. That will produce the "New Line in Constant" error because it 'escapes' the second quote so that it doesn't count. And the string isn't closed.

Use either `"\\"` (escaping the `\` with itself)
or use `@"\"` (a verbatim string).

Answer (score 2):

The Backslash in string literals is an escape character, so it must either be escaped itself:

```
"\\"
```

Or you can use a so-called verbatim string literal:

```
@"\"
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090.aspx

Regarding your compile error: The backslash escapes the following quotation mark, thus the string literal is not recognized as closed. The following characters ) and ; are valid for string literals, however the line ending (newline) is not. Hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

That will only replace 1 single quote.
To get them all use:

```
string cat1_escaped = cat1.Replace("'", "\'");
```

Although a lot of databases don't escape quotes like that, but rather by doubling them:

```
string cat1_escaped = cat1.Replace("'", "''");
```

Comment: Don't forget to escape the backslash ;)