# Trying to Resolve error cs1010 newline in constant "string concat value is not appearing properly"

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I' m trying to resolve error cs1010 newline in constant.

At this Line

```
if ((image1.Source==new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Object/ob_" + CI + "_" + LI + ".png", UriKind.Absolute))) &&(objNameWritten1.Text==objnamewritten[LI]))
```

The output is"ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Object/ob_0"
but it should be

"ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Object/ob_0_0"
Where is the Error Exactly

Cs code

```
private void common()
        {

            if (CI > 10)
            {
                CI = 0;
                return;
            }
            if (HeaderName.Text== Headername[CI])
            {
                int LI = 0;
                for (int i = 3*CI+LI; i < 3*(CI+1); LI++)
                {
                    if ((image1.Source==new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Object/ob_" + CI + "_" + LI + ".png", UriKind.Absolute))) &&(objNameWritten1.Text==objnamewritten[LI]))
                    {
                        ppup.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
                        ppup.IsOpen = true;
                        CI++;
                        HeaderName.Text = Headername[CI];
                        common();
                    }
                    else if ((image2.Source == new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Object/ob_" + CI + "_" + LI + ".png"))) && (objNameWritten2.Text == objnamewritten[LI]))
                    {
                        ppup.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
                        ppup.IsOpen = true;
                        CI++;
                        HeaderName.Text = Headername[CI];
                        common();
                    }
                    else if ((image3.Source == new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Object/ob_" + CI + "_" + LI + ".png"))) && (objNameWritten3.Text == objnamewritten[LI]))
                    {
                        ppup.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
                        ppup.IsOpen = true;
                        CI++;
                        HeaderName.Text = Headername[CI];
                        common();
                    }

                }

            }
            else
            {
                ppup1.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
                ppup1.IsOpen = true;
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New Line in Constant error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17739612/new-line-in-constant-error)

Comment: I saw that but it is some thing different than the issue which the link refer

Comment: Do you get the same error if you set a variable to "ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Object/ob_" + CI + "_" + LI + ".png" so you can debug what is there, and then use that in your code?

Comment: Try like this? `new BitmapImage(new Uri(string.Format("ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Object/ob_{0}_{1}.png",CI,LI), UriKind.Absolute)))`

Comment: @AVKNaidu I tried this but it did n't solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code on my side. There is nothing wrong with string concat. The uri result is `ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Object/ob_0_0.png` which is right. Here is the screenshot of the result. You can also print out your concat result as following picture shows. [image]

The error actually for your if condition is that you compare a [`BitmapImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx) with [`ImageSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imagesource.aspx) in your code snippet. For judging whether the `ImageSource` is equal with one picture, you can use code as follows:

```
if((image1.Source as BitmapImage).UriSource== new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/LearnColor/Object/ob_" + CI + "_" + LI + ".png", UriKind.Absolute))
```